# Check string by user-given regex

Tags: python, regex, django

I one of my Django app, I need to make a string validation using flags. What I mean:
in admin panel, I add for example:

- `baduser*@gmail.com`
- `spambot-?@gmail.com`

etc...

There won't be strict pythonic regex, but '*' or '?' provided by common admin

While someone is signing up, i must check all that credentials by Python regex.
I need to check:

- `*` as any sign, one or multiple times
- `?` as 1 sign.

Any ideas how could I make that?

Comment: is `baduser@gmailxcom` a valid address or are the flags valid for the username only?

Comment: baduser*@gmail.com is a string provided by admin. That expression should block for example: baduserlorem@gmail.com, baduserlalala@gmail.com etc.
I must, somehow, escape valid email signs like '.' and '+' which are special chars in regex i think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd translate that to a regular expression, then use that to match against email addresses.

That's not that hard to do:

```
import re

def translate_pattern(pattern):
    res = []
    for c in pattern:
        if c == '*':
            res.append('.+')  # 1 or more
        elif c == '.':
            res.append('.')   # exactly 1
        else:
            res.append(re.escape(c))  # anything else is a literal character
    return re.compile(''.join(res))
```

The function returns ready-compiled regular expressions:

```
>>> translate_pattern('baduser*@gmail.com').search('baduser12345@gmail.com')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x107467780>
>>> translate_pattern('baduser*@gmail.com').search('gooduser@gmail.com')
```

Do note that because you match on `.` as *any* character, the following matches too:

```
>>> translate_pattern('baduser*@gmail.com').search('baduser12345@gmail-com')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1074677e8>
```

because the `.` matches the `-` in `gmail-com`.